# insert a specific line after occurrence with Unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I need insert a new line with specific content after find a pattern in text1 file with shell.

I have a file `text_file_1.txt` with this content:

```
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
patternrefrefref
cccccc
aaaaaa
patternasdasd
pattern
zzzzzz
```

and a `text_file_2.txt` with this content:

```
111111
333333
555555
```

and I need insert the first line of `text_file_2.txt` (that is, `111111`) when I find the first occurrence of "pattern" of `text_file_1.txt` and `333333` when I find the second occurrence of "pattern (always pattern)...

Final result will be:

```
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
pattern_refrefref
111111
cccccc
aaaaaa
pattern_asdasd
3333333
pattern
555555
zzzzzz
```

I found how to insert a new line with a new text after a pattern but always insert the same text, I don't need that.

Comment: Please work on formatting your question properly.

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it fail?  I would turn to Awk (hint: `NR==FNR`), though I guess it could be possible to do in `sed` as well.

Comment: I have tried something like this: 
sed '/pattern/a 111111' file

Comment: sorry @derlarsschneider my english es poor ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easily done using awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0; next} 1; /pattern/{print a[++i]}' text_file_2.txt text_file_1.txt

aaaaaa
bbbbbb
patternrefrefref
111111
cccccc
aaaaaa
patternasdasd
333333
pattern
555555
zzzzzz
```

- In the first block `FNR==NR` we are reading all the lines from file2 and storing them in an indexed array `a`.
- While iterating through file2 whenever we encounter `pattern` we print one line from array and increment the counter.

Comment: It's awesome! it's work fine :D thank you very much. You have got that I waste a lot of hours working on files manually ^_^

Answer (score 2):

i think you are looking for something like this...

```
sed '/what_you_want_to_find /a what_you_want_to_add' text_file_1.txt
```

if you also want to save the changes in the same file just use this:

```
sed -i '/what_you_want_to_find /a what_you_want_to_add' text_file_1.txt
```

to help you a bit more, at the point that you add what new you want to get printed, so in `what_you_want_to_add`, you can do it like this.
Save each line every time in variable outside of the sed, 
for example you want to get line number 5.

```
line= awk 'NR==5' text_file_2.txt
```

and you can use the variable each time to print the new line, so it would like this in your case.
sed '/what_you_want_to_find /a $line' text_file_1.txt